# Compute Sum of Integers in a Binary Tree of Tuples with Python

Tags: python, tree, binary, sum, tuples

I've been having a particularly hard time understanding this concept, and my professor did not cover the topic very well. The problem requires me to write a function that compute the sum of the integers that make up a binary tree made of tuples.

I am provided with the following code:

`node_one = (None, 1, None)
node_two = (node_one, 2, node_one)
node_three = (node_two, 3, None) 
node_four = (node_three, 4, node_three)`

I need to write a function that accepts node_four as an argument and returns a count of the integers in the tree as follows:

`def TreeSum(t):
    #fill in`

`TreeSum(node_four)  # This should return 18`

If you can help me understand how to go about solving this problem I'd have your eternal gratitude!

Answer (score 1):

If you forget all about tuples and other implementation details and focus on trees,

- If the tree is empty, the sum is 0
- Otherwise, it's the sum of the number in "this node" and the sums of the subtrees.

In Python:

```
def tree_sum(t):
    return 0 if is_empty(t) else data(t) + tree_sum(left(t)) + tree_sum(right(t))
```

Note that this is completely independent of how the trees are represented.

Now we can add the tree-related functions for "tuple trees":

```
def is_empty(t):
    return t is None

def data(t):
    return t[1]

def left(t):
    return t[0]

def right(t):
    return t[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the prompt!
Here is the solution that worked:

`sum = 0`

`def TreeSum(t):
    global sum`

```
for i in range(len(t)):
    if t[i] == node_three:
        TreeSum(node_three)
    elif t[i] == node_two:
        TreeSum(node_two)
    elif t[i] == node_one:
        TreeSum(node_one)
    elif t[i] == None:
        pass
    else:
        sum += t[i]
return sum
```

`TreeSum(node_four)  # This should return 18`

Comment: Your solution should work for any tree, not just that specific example.